# How to enable scrollbar in draggable jquery-ui div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scrollbar, jquery-ui-draggable

I try to make a draggable div with jquery-ui, but with lot of text in, so there is a scrollbar in this div and I want to enable this scrollbar. The problem is when I want to use the scrollbar, it drags the div instead of drags only the bar. 
I use :

```
   $( "Selector" ).draggable();
```

For more explanation look this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DHk2/) (there is only the concerned div) and try to use the scroll bar

Sorry for my poor English

Comment: On Chrome this works exactly how I would expect it to.  You move the scrollbar, it scrolls the content of the thing it's connected to. Can you describe the issue more clearly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i must to create an application only usable on mozilla firefox 21, and on this browser the bar doesn't scroll, when I drag the bar, all the box is drag and it not scroll the bar. (effectively in chrome it works but not in firefox, so how can i make it work on firefox ? )

Comment: I think you need to update your question to clearly state that "Firefox 21"  a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Replace your div Default scroll bar with jScrollPane

jScrollPane is a cross-browser jQuery plugin which converts a browser's default scrollbars on elements with a relevant overflow property into an HTML structure which can be easily skinned with CSS.

JSFiddle Demo : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/glryu/2/).

```
        <div class="scroll-pane">
            <p>Vivamus  hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus  rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie  magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum  feugiat nisl ut dapibus.</p>
            <p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam pulvinar, odio sed rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat purus metus eu velit. Proin metus odio, aliquam eget molestie nec, gravida ut sapien. Phasellus quis est sed turpis sollicitudin venenatis sed eu odio. Praesent eget neque eu eros interdum malesuada non vel leo. Sed fringilla porta ligula egestas tincidunt. Nullam risus magna, ornare vitae varius eget, scelerisque a libero. Morbi eu porttitor ipsum. Nullam lorem nisi, posuere quis volutpat eget, luctus nec massa. Pellentesque aliquam lacinia tellus sit amet bibendum. Ut posuere justo in enim pretium scelerisque. Etiam ornare vehicula euismod. Vestibulum at risus augue. Sed non semper dolor. Sed fringilla consequat velit a porta. Pellentesque sed lectus pharetra ipsum ultricies commodo non sit amet velit. Suspendisse volutpat lobortis ipsum, in scelerisque nisi iaculis a. Duis pulvinar lacinia commodo. Integer in lorem id nibh luctus aliquam. Sed elementum, est ac sagittis porttitor, neque metus ultricies ante, in accumsan massa nisl non metus. Vivamus sagittis quam a lacus dictum tempor. Nullam in semper ipsum. Cras a est id massa malesuada tincidunt. Etiam a urna tellus. Ut rutrum vehicula dui, eu cursus magna tincidunt pretium. Donec malesuada accumsan quam, et commodo orci viverra et. Integer tincidunt sagittis lectus. Mauris ac ligula quis orci auctor tincidunt. Suspendisse odio justo, varius id.</p>
            <p>Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla, orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim. Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum. Etiam scelerisque, nunc ac egestas consequat, odio nibh euismod.</p>
        </div>
```

SCRIPT INIT

```
var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
```

FOR MORE REFERENCE
[jscrollpane Main Site](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/).